# Huge screen tearing on Ubuntu Budgie 23.04. Intel graphics. No problem on 22.04.2 and 22.10

Tags: intel-graphics, 23.04, tearing, ubuntu-budgie

So I switched from Ubuntu Budgie 22.10 to 23.04 - and instantly the screen tearing problems happened after system update.

Everything is fine on 22.04.2 and 22.10. I now rolled back to 22.04.2.

I tried a bunch of stuff on 23.04- I tried to create 20-intel.conf with:

> Section "Device"
>
> Identifier "Intel Graphics"
>
> Driver "intel"
>
> Option "TearFree" "true"
>
> EndSection

An nothing improved.

What else can I try to remove this issue on 23.04? Any ideas?

Didn't saw any posts whatsoever about other users issues similar to mine on 23.04, so maybe its not that common.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help- much appreciated since I would love to test 23.04 build but these issues are really destroying my user experience to the point of rolling back.